# Android Pie emulator with com.android.future.usb

Tags: android, android-emulator, usb

I am trying to run my app on an Android Pie emulator (tried several models: Nexus, Pixel, etc.) 
On every emulator I get the `INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY` error:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY: Package couldn't be installed in ...: Package  requires unavailable shared library com.android.future.usb.accessory; failing!]
Error while Installing APK
```

How can I install the missing library on the emulator?

Comment: I doubt emulators support USB Accessory mode, seeing as they have no USB interface.

Comment: @TheWanderer my app is able to be opened on emulators with api lvls <= 24. After that, it doesnt install

Comment: @TheWanderer update: api lvl 27 also is ok. The problems are with 25, 26, 28